# Kendo UI Stock Chart Navigator Broken

Tags: javascript, css, html, kendo-ui

A while back I made a kendo stock chart, and it worked perfectly. Then my co-worker went through and was polishing off all of the styles on the front end and I think that might be why my stock chart's navigator is showing up like this:
[image]
My styling on the div that we call .kendoStockChart on is:

```
color: #2E2E2E;
display: block;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
height: 513.328125px;
line-height: normal;
position: relative;
width: 805.640625px;
```

I really hope I'm missing something obvious, any tips or attempts at answers are appreciated!

**Edit:** Sorry to all that have been trying to help me with this, been out of the office for a couple weeks since I opened this, will let you know if it gets fixed when I go back soon.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question... what is wrong?

Comment: The bottom part(called the navigator) is broken. Compare to their working examples: http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/financial/index.html

Comment: You mean the handle positions? When I go their example and set position: relative on their element.style in Chrome, I get a similar result.  Make sure .k-handle has position: absolute and .k-selector has 100% height.

Comment: The handlers of the navigator are styled using the classes `k-handle`, `k-rightHandle` and `k-leftHandle`. They have nothing to do with the styles that you posted in the original question. I'm afraid that you will have to share actual code / style for helping us to guess what is wrong.

Comment: If your browser has developer tools check the styles for the handlers looking for something suspicious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it could be a problem with missing css files. Have you made sure that you've included all of Kendo's files correctly?

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I missed that. I didn't have my `kendo.dataviz.min.css` file included...

Answer (score 2):

Check your CSS styles on `<a>` tags, I think that might be messing with your navigator selector.

You may just want to do a "binary" search on the CSS stylesheet: Comment out half and see if it fixes the problem. If not, try the other half. If either one fixes the problem then try commenting out each half of that portion, and so on until you find your offending styles. (Assuming CSS is the issue here)

Comment: I don't see any <a> tags in any of the children of the chart's main div(and by children i mean any sub-elements of the main div), so don't think this is affecting it

Comment: Did you try removing sections of the stylesheet as suggested? If so, did you find anything?